# retrieve original url of a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that, wordpress redirects closely matched urls to its original url.However, I need to know the actual url at the very beginning of code execution. Is it possible?

1) If there is any method that takes a url as parameter and returns its original wordpress url
, that would be great, but not sure, whether it exists or not. Is there something like that?

2) where in the code actually does this test and redirection please?

3) Is there any hook that I can use to add a plugin to control this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Example:

Suppose, I have a post on this url: "http://mydomain.com/example-post-page"

Now if I try to access it via "http://mydomain.com/example-post-page/", it will redirect you to original first url. It is true for other several small changes in url, all will redirect you to the actual permalink url.

My goal is to control this redirection. That's why, when I am on "http://mydomain.com/example-post-page/" , I like to know(my code in on root index.php) whether this is the origianl permalink or is that something else, before it redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, At last I got it done in the following way and seems ok for me:

1) Recieve approx url.
2) Make a cURL request using this approx url.
3) get response url.
4) return the response url.

Code given below:

```
function get_actual_url($approx_url){
$curlObj = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, $approx_url);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,180);

$content = curl_exec($curlObj);

$info = curl_getinfo($curlObj);
curl_close($curlObj);

if(!empty($info) && !empty($info["url"])){
    return $info["url"];
}
else {
    return $approx_url;
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do this in PHP, you can ask the server what the requested URL was. try accessing $_SERVER[ ] and see if this has what you are looking for. 
(protip: to see an entire variable in php, use `print_r($_SERVER);`)

I executed the command on my wordpress site and got back:

```
 Array
(
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [REQUEST_URI] => /wordpress_NEWURL/cookbook/
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL] => /wordpress_NEWURL/cookbook/
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI] => http://openmdao.org/wordpress_NEWURL/cookbook/
    [REDIRECT_HTTPS] => off
    [REDIRECT_X-FORWARDED-PROTO] => http
    [REDIRECT_X-FORWARDED-SSL] => off
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SCRIPT_URL] => /wordpress_NEWURL/cookbook/
    [SCRIPT_URI] => http://openmdao.org/wordpress_NEWURL/cookbook/
    [HTTPS] => off
    [X-FORWARDED-PROTO] => http
    [X-FORWARDED-SSL] => off
    [HTTP_HOST] => openmdao.org
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST] => openmdao.org
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER] => openmdao.org
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 128.156.10.80
    [HTTP_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => http
    [HTTP_HTTPS] => off
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => http
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL] => off
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 92
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_ORIGIN] => http://openmdao.org
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_REFERER] => http://openmdao.org/wordpress_NEWURL/cookbook/
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => wp-settings-1=m7%3Do%26m11%3Do%26wplink%3D0%26editor%3Dtinymce%26hidetb%3D1%26align%3Dright; wp-settings-time-1=1341576701; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_7f72de226f3f83cb831f7a36bd420125=admin%7C1342021433%7C1c54f9729f967300e8d1ecc80eea7e38; w3tc_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fopenmdao.org%2Fwordpress_test%2Fsdk-1.5.6.2%2F_samples%2F; wp-settings-1=m7%3Do%26m11%3Do%26wplink%3D0; wp-settings-time-1=1339595284; greeting_set=True; _gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; PHPSESSID=0302b71abfbfd5a8d7854ac168aba2f9; sessionid=7b87104b87d95624cab0fe282079aa07; csrftoken=e72c25d0cdc3a6682c89e4680742ff3b; __utma=192130932.1535996015.1339438190.1341938618.1341945509.58; __utmc=192130932; __utmz=192130932.1339605598.7.2.utmcsr=rss|utmccn=new-website|utmcmd=rss
    [HTTP_VIA] => 1.1 www-fw.grc.nasa.gov 8B58912A
    [PATH] => /usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/home/ph/trunk/python-hosting.com/new_site/monitor:/home/ph/trunk/python-hosting.com/new_site/manual_scripts:/root/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_NAME] => openmdao.org
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 128.156.10.80
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/openmdao/webapps/_
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/openmdao/webapps/wp_test/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 51907
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /wordpress_NEWURL/cookbook/
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /wordpress_NEWURL/index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /wordpress_NEWURL/index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1341948361
    [argv] => Array
        (
        )

    [argc] => 0
)
```

Any one of those paramaters can be accessed by $_SERVER['PARAMATER'] from anywhere in you script. 
I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Hi, in this way, I will only able to know my current url(even if that is wrong). But, no way I can be sure, is this the original url or not.

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by 'original URL.' Do you mean the permalink to the page? Because wordpress stores those in its database (accessible by a plugin or theme)

Comment: hi, yes, that's permalink I am talking about. to access it from db, you will need to know the post id, right? but when you are on very earlier, like on index.php, you don't know that. ALl you have is the url string, which is wrong as well. So, in no way I can directly query to db for retrieving. Also, I have added an example scenario as it seems I didn't able to clear enough. Let me know, if it makes sense now.

Comment: So are you saying that if I have a url like: `http://mydomain.com/example-post-page?somevar=something` that you are trying to differentiate that from `http://mydomain.com/example-post-page`. Or are you talking about being redirected to something like `http://mydomain.com/236`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the_permalink? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

Comment: Hi, yes, I did mean the permalink. Problem is that, if you are on a wrong url, you will be redirected before you can call this "the_permalink" method.